# strange results with .strip .lstrip including a slash ( '/' )

Tags: python, strip

(examples using python 3.8 on Ubuntu Linux 20.4 64Bit):

```
>>> a="/get/todo.dat"
>>> b="/get/"
>>> a.lstrip(b)
'odo.dat'

expected:
'todo.dat'
```

even worse:

```
expected answer in each case:
'0018.dat'

# first test of lstrip()
>>> name='data/rwl3_v001_Data0018.dat'
>>> mask='data/rwl3_v001_Data'
>>> name.lstrip(mask)
'8.dat'

# strip() should return the same answer:
>>> name.strip(mask)
'8.'
```

while '/t' might be misinterpreted maybe as tab '\t'  (?) the second example puzzles me even more.

Any Ideas what happens? Help appreciated. Of course I could write a function, but is there something to know about strings and strip?

Comment: `strip` accepts a list/iterable of the characters to remove, **not** a string

Comment: `strip` removes all the occurrences of the provided iterable.

Comment: you can use regex or `find` method of string

Comment: A workable solution to the problem using regex: `re.sub('^' + re.escape(mask), '', name)` for lstrip, `re.sub(re.escape(mask) + '$', '', name)` for rstrip

Comment: Next time, first check the [documentation on the method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lstrip) you're using, which in this case happens to suggest [the correct function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.removeprefix) for what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

strip accepts a list/iterable of the characters to remove, not a string.

Here you request to remove all `/`, `g`, `e`, `t` from both ends of `a`.

Use `split` instead: `a.rsplit('/')[-1]`, or a dedicated library to parse/handle paths.

Comment: @peets you can also use `replace` method of string, use count as 1